Regula - facecheck & React : CORS problem
I created a new ReactJS application (with ViteJS) simply to test the liveness and face checking of [regulaforensics][1]. by clicking on Go to start and activating the camera it gives me the possibility to accept the permissions but just after it returns a CORS problem:
Access to fetch at 'https://faceapi.regulaforensics.com/api/v2/liveness/start' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

this is how I implement the regula library:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "@regulaforensics/vp-frontend-face-components";
function App() {
  const [faceType, setFaceType] = useState("liveness");
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("fr");
  useEffect(() => {
    const settings = {
      locale: lang,
      closeDisabled: true,
      videoRecording: false,
      // url: "your/server/url",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
      },

  
    };


    const component = document.getElementsByTagName(
      faceType === "liveness" ? "face-liveness" : "face-capture"
    )[0];
    if (component) {
      component.settings = settings;
    }
  }, [lang, faceType]);
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h1>
        eKYC by ZEDLAB -{" "}
        {faceType === "liveness" ? "La Vivacité" : "Reconnaissance Faciale"}
      </h1>
      <div>
          <face-liveness>
            <h1>TEST CHILD</h1>
          </face-liveness>
      </div>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setLang(lang === "fr" ? "en" : "fr")}
      >
        {lang === "fr" ? "English" : "Français"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

